# React native bottomsheet with “formSheet” screen (ios)

Tags: ios, react-native, bottom-sheet, stack-navigator

Perhaps someone faced such a problem.
I have

```
<Stack.Screen
    name={"myScreen"}
    component={MyScreen}
    options={{
        animation: 'slide_from_bottom',
        presentation: 'formSheet',
        gestureEnabled: true
    }}
 />
```

On this screen, I have a button, when I click on it, I open BottomSheetModal from the gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet library.
I wrapped this screen in a BottomSheetModalProvider because without it BottomSheetModal won't open on ios.

If there are just components inside the BottomSheetModal, then everything works as it should (when you swipe down on the content and on the top bar, the BottomSheetModal closes). When inside BottomSheetModal there is a component that will scroll, for example BottomSheetFlatList, when you swipe down on the content, both BottomSheetModal and the screen itself are closed, since it has a "formSheet".
If you set scrollEnabled={false}, everything works as it should

If you set scrollEnabled={false}, everything works as it should.